# I need to pass the Clients thread culture to WCF Service.

Tags: c#

I need to pass the Clients thread culture to WCF Service. What is the best way to do that? If that is by passing the culture information in header, then how do we do that.

Comment: Simply make the culture a parameter of the WCF service method.

Comment: I have Service which has lot of Methods, That would be lot of changes. I figured below way in POC, where be add the Message Header by using OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(webUserHeader);  And on the service side we have to fetch that from header and then send it.

Comment: But then again in the service side we have to explicitly set that, I was looking in to the way it automatically takes Clients thread culture. Like it tales the client machine culture when we set it in the web config by using <globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" />

Comment: I found the Answer. Pass the Culture information as MessageHeader. and then in the Service constructor, you can take the Culture information and initialize the service culture. In case someone needs to the code ex. add comments I will provide the details

Comment: There's a WSI18N implementation for WCF here, or it's easy to roll your own: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15737/Globalization-Patterns-in-WCF-WS-I-N-implementati

Comment: the one we pass the message header is quick and easier. Provided, if we  have a big application where the services all called at various places, but the but the object is created at single place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Answer. Pass the Culture information as MessageHeader. and then in the Service constructor, you can take the Culture information and initialize the service culture. In case someone needs to the code ex. add comments I will provide the details